# Getting UTF-8 in Flask from MySQL with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my MySQL database:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS freshleafy CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I am entering Devanagari script: नमस्ते

I have tried the following:

```
mysql://...?use_unicode=1&charset=utf8
mysql://...?use_unicode=1&charset=utf8mb4
```

All I get is ?????? when I print the data.

I need to get it in the original text which will be transferred to a mobile application when this API is called.

Additional Info - When I export it into a csv file the characters don't come out correctly. example -this- अरबी, turns into this - à¤…à¤°à¤¬à¥€

Comment: Are you sure your terminal emulator is capable of displaying these characters?

Comment: Yep, pretty sure. I tried printing the characters directly, and they worked.

Comment: You got past the `SyntaxError` then? You should edit that out of the post.

Comment: done that :) now I think it's some sort of encoding problem. though cannot figure out what. Have to look at the MySQL documentation again.

Comment: I still get ??? when I try to fetch it from the db though.